Webpack not running ESLint plugin in Grunt
I am using Webpack with the ESLintPlugin within Grunt in JetBrains IDE.  On my previous machine, the setup worked fine using a grunt call to webpack with this plugin:
plugins: [
    new ESLintPlugin(
        {
            extensions: ['ts'],
        }
    ),
],

And I thought it worked once on a new machine before failing utterly.  Strangely it works fine with just grunt on the command line, it works great within webpack alone, but something is failing to run the plugin only with this obscure combination.  This is on MacOS Sequoia. (Solved below)

The difference between calling grunt in the terminal and from Jetbrains IDE came down to the latter specifying the full path to the Gruntfile.js:
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v22.11.0/bin/node
    /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v22.11.0/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt 
    --gruntfile /Users/me/git/my_project/Gruntfile.js 
    dev

Jetbrains specifies the full path to the Gruntfile.js -- the issue is that at some point I renamed my git directory to capital Git (it was the only folder in my home directory w/ lowercase and it hurt my aesthetic).  MacOS is case-insensitive, so this should not matter, but apparently it does for one of grunt-webpack or grunt-eslint or something.  Changing the path to the gruntfile to have proper capitalization fixed the problem.

"the issue is that at some point I renamed my git directory to capital Git" Where/how did you rename it?. I mean -- was it in a terminal or in Finder? Most likely you will see different capitalisation for that git folder in terminal and Finder. If so -- try the following: rename that Git to some completely different name (e.g. my-git ) and then rename to the desired name (Git as I understand). I have seen it a few times when renaming a folder in Finder while changing only capitalisation, the changes are not "fully applied" (old capitalisation remains when checking in terminal).
